# Why is there a BEGIN and END in the IF clause but not the ELSE clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can someone explain why in the example

```
DECLARE @compareprice money, @cost money 
EXECUTE Production.uspGetList '%Bikes%', 700, 
    @compareprice OUT, 
    @cost OUTPUT
IF @cost <= @compareprice 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'These products can be purchased for less than 
    $'+RTRIM(CAST(@compareprice AS varchar(20)))+'.'
END
ELSE
    PRINT 'The prices for all products in this category exceed 
    $'+ RTRIM(CAST(@compareprice AS varchar(20)))+'.'
```

on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx there is a `BEGIN` and `END` enclosing the `IF` block but not the `ELSE` block?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258853(v=sql.80).aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @RahulTripathi That example you posted has `BEGIN` and `END` around both the `IF` and `ELSE` blocks. So it doesn't help me understand my question.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific reason for it. It just is. You can freely remove the `BEGIN...END` in the `IF` clause, or you can add them in the `ELSE` without changing the meaning of the code.

Comment: For single SQL Statement, there's no need for BEGIN and END. If you try to add multiple statement it will give you syntax error. Just try this at your end.

Answer (score 3):

`BEGIN` and `END` are optional when there is only one statement.  In this example, they are not required in either the `IF` or the `ELSE` clause because there is only a single statement.  It could have been written like this:

```
IF @cost <= @compareprice 
    PRINT 'These products can be purchased for less than 
    $'+RTRIM(CAST(@compareprice AS varchar(20)))+'.'
ELSE
    PRINT 'The prices for all products in this category exceed 
    $'+ RTRIM(CAST(@compareprice AS varchar(20)))+'.'
```